# selecting css properties value from inline style using xpath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

```
<a href="http://link.com">
 <div style="background-image:url(https://imageurl.jpeg);">
  </div>
</a>
```

Is there a selector in xpath that allows for getting the value of a certain css declaration, bearing in mind that it is an inline style.

In the code example above I want to retrieve the value of the "background-image" prop.

Comment: consider using "selenium webdriver" or Python "scrapy" module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the xpath :

`substring-before(substring-after(//div/@style, 'background-image:url('), ')')`

Comment: perfect answer, basically find the beginning and end of the characters surrounding the url. thanks!